# How to send a search term in a url that paginates the results

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a simple form to search a table for the search term entered into that form.

```
$query = $_GET['term'];
$min_length = 1;
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){
   $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
   $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $query);
}
```

Here the variable 'query' is the search query posted from the form.

The query for the database looks like this

```
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR   
`brand` LIKE '%".$query."%'
OR `description` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `spec` LIKE '%".$query."%'
OR `category` LIKE '%".$query."%' OR `subcategory` LIKE '%".$query."%' AND status = 1 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage")  OR die(mysqli_error($link));
```

So this works ok if I dont paginate results, but I need to paginate them.

I think I need to get this line of code to send the variable '$query' to each paginated page.

```
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?$query&currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
```

'$x' is just the variable for the current page

My form is now set to method="get"

**EDIT:** Sorted (I think)

I had everything wrapped in a

```
if(isset( $_GET['submit'] ) ){
}
```

So it appears to me that when I went to any other page but the first page (the first time) that submit from my search form wasn't being posted again obviously, so there were no results to get.

When I took that 'if' out the pagination works. But is it ok not to have it?

Comment: Send the query via the URL, not the post headers. In other words, in your form method, set it to `get`, and change `$_POST['term']` to `$_GET['term']`.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy, make your url pretty like :
mysite.com/mypage/classified/3, so you just have to change the pagination number ("3") //
(without url rewriting mysite.com/mypage.foo&term="classified"&currentpage="3")

Comment: Question edited again!

Comment: Do you need to give an indicator as to the total number of "pages" anywhere in your application?

Comment: No, it just split the results into pages of 12 (or less on the last page). So if there are 120 result then there are 10 pages. Like i say in my edit

Comment: i removed the 'if (isset(_$GET(submit))){}' it works. But is it safe to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward term parameter and current page index. Also you must add

```
offset $x*$pagesize
limit $pagesize
```

to your query...

Comment: Ive edited the query to include the offset and limit. My code had this but i seemed to have deleted them when i pasted here. I have also done othe edits..........

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts here:

Before even getting into the pagination aspects, just by looking at your query, I would suggest you look at using a MySQL natural language full text search (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).  that would make your query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE
  MATCH (name, brand, description, spec, category, subcategory)
    AGAINST :query
  AND STATUS = 1
```

This requires a `FULLTEXT` index across the fields used in the search.  This requires use of MyISAM engine for the table.

An interesting thing to note about using the full text search in the where clause like this is that it will return rows in order of "relevance".  So, for example, a record that has a number of matches across DB columns for you search term will have higher relevance than a record with a single match. In most search uses cases like yours, this is desired behavior, and your current query does nothing at all to provide this sort of functionality.

Now on to pagination.

You would likely need to pass some additional parameters to indicate page.  So say your parameters are like this:

```
// you should provide some validation for these parameters, but I am not showing that
$query = $_GET['term'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

You would also somewhere in your code have some value set to determine rows per page to be shown. This could even be in the form of a parameter as well if you want to let the user select number of rows per page.

```
$rows_per_page = $_GET['pagerows'];
// or simply something like $rows_per_page = 10;
```

Calculation of values to use in the LIMIT clause is trivial. I am assuming `$page` is 1-based (i.e. first page has value of 1)

```
$offset = ($page - 1) * $rows_per_page;
```

Putting it together with the query above you get:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE
  MATCH (name, brand, description, spec, category, subcategory)
    AGAINST :query
  AND STATUS = 1
LIMIT :offset, :pagerows
```

Note I am just using named parameter syntax in the queries.  You should consider using prepared statements for these queries.

So that is is the simple use case.  Now what if you want to show the user some indication as to the number of pages associated with the search result? This means that you need to understand how many rows the query would return if there was no `LIMIT` clause.  There are a couple of ways of doing this.  You could simply run the same query without the `LIMIT` first and get the number of rows from that query.  This may be appropriate for cases where you were not accepting user input to filter the result set and the user could arrive in the pagination view on any arbitrary page number.

That does not seem to be the use cases realted to a search, so I will give you another option which may best suite the search query use case.  That is the use of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` keyword in conjunction with `FOUND_ROWS()` functions.  Here is how it works.

You simply add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` into you SELECT query like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM products
WHERE
  MATCH (name, brand, description, spec, category, subcategory)
    AGAINST :query
  AND STATUS = 1
LIMIT :offset, :pagerows
```

Your query will return the paginated result as expected, but using the same DB connection, you can then make a follow-up query to get the number of "found rows" (i.e. rows in result set before applying `LIMIT` from the last query).  That query is very simple:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

So here is how this may look from a coding perspective:

```
$sql = <<<EOT
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM products
WHERE
  MATCH (name, brand, description, spec, category, subcategory)
    AGAINST :query
  AND STATUS = 1
LIMIT :offset, :pagerows
EOT;

// perform query here

// work with your result set
while ($row = /* your row fetch logic here */) {
    // do something with row
}

// now query DB again to get found rows
// you must use same DB connection used for initial query
// and you must not perform any queries between your initial
// SELECT and this query to get row count 
$row_sql = 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()';

// execute your query and read the value from the result
// lets assume you set this to a variable named $total_rows

// now simply determine number of available page by simple math and rounding
$page_count = ceil($total_rows / $rows_per_page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:

**pagination.php**

```
<?php
function getPagingQuery($sql, $itemPerPage = 10)
{
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && (int)$_GET['page'] > 0) {
        $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    // start fetching from this row number
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $itemPerPage;

    return $sql . " LIMIT $offset, $itemPerPage";

}
function getPagingLink($sql, $itemPerPage = 10,$strGet)
{
    $result        = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $pagingLink    = '';
    $totalResults  = mysql_numrows($result);


    $totalPages    = ceil($totalResults / $itemPerPage);


    // how many link pages to show
    $numLinks      = 10;


    // create the paging links only if we have more than one page of results
    if ($totalPages > 1) {

        $self = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;

        if (isset($_GET['page']) && (int)$_GET['page'] > 0) {
            $pageNumber = (int)$_GET['page'];
        } else {
            $pageNumber = 1;
        }

        // print 'previous' link only if we're not
        // on page one
        if ($pageNumber > 1) {
            $page = $pageNumber - 1;
            if ($page > 1) {
                $prev = " <a href=\"$self?page=$page&$strGet\" class=\"paging\">[Prev]</a> ";
            } else {
                $prev = " <a href=\"$self?$strGet\" class=\"paging\">[Prev]</a> ";
            }   

            $first = " <a href=\"$self?$strGet\" class=\"paging\">[First]</a> ";
        } else {
            $prev  = ''; // we're on page one, don't show 'previous' link
            $first = ''; // nor 'first page' link
        }

        // print 'next' link only if we're not
        // on the last page
        if ($pageNumber < $totalPages) {
            $page = $pageNumber + 1;
            $next = " <a href=\"$self?page=$page&$strGet\" class=\"paging\">[Next]</a> ";
            $last = " <a href=\"$self?page=$totalPages&$strGet\" class=\"paging\">[Last]</a> ";
        } else {
            $next = ''; // we're on the last page, don't show 'next' link
            $last = ''; // nor 'last page' link
        }

        $start = $pageNumber - ($pageNumber % $numLinks) + 1;
        $end   = $start + $numLinks - 1;        

        $end   = min($totalPages, $end);

        $pagingLink = array();
        for($page = $start; $page <= $end; $page++) {
            if ($page == $pageNumber) {

                $pagingLink[] = " $page ";   // no need to create a link to current page
            } else {
                if ($page == 1) {

                    $pagingLink[] = " <a href=\"$self?$strGet\" class=\"paging\">$page</a> ";
                } else {    

                    $pagingLink[] = " <a href=\"$self?page=$page&$strGet\" class=\"paging\">$page</a> ";
                }   
            }

        }

        $pagingLink = implode(' | ', $pagingLink);

        // return the page navigation link
        $pagingLink = $first . $prev . $pagingLink . $next . $last;

    }

    return $pagingLink;
}
?>
```

**product_search.php**

```
$query = $_GET['term'];
$select = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$query."%' ";

$strget="term=".$query;
$rowsPerPage =10;
$result= mysql_query(getPagingQuery($sel_products, $rowsPerPage, $strget)) or die(mysql_error());
$pagingLink = getPagingLink($sel_products, $rowsPerPage, $strget); 
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($result);

if($num_rows > 0) {
        while($array_in= mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
        $product_id = $array_in['id'];
        $product_name = $array_in['name'];
        }

echo $pagingLink;

}
else
{
echo "No Results To Display";
}
```

I hope it should work.